# Can someone tell me what this line of code means?

Tags: c

What does this line of code mean?

```
if((c-a)!=0 && (d-b)!=0) goto trap;
```

What does the `!=`mean?
I inherited this, and I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c+operators

Comment: Huh? Did you read a beginner C language guide?

Comment: @H2CO3; Suggest for him.

Comment: @haccks http://google.com/search?q=beginner+c+tutorial. He will eventually find http://c-faq.com as well.

Comment: Huh? You "inherited" this piece of code and you have difficulty with the `!=`? Are you familiar with C programming *at all*?

Answer (score 3):

It means: if `c` is not equal to `a`, then if `d` and `b` are also not equal, goto (jump to) the line with the label "trap".

The `!=`, just means not equal. It is the complement of the `==` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Not equal.

1 != 2

1 == 1

2 != 1

3 != 5

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, not seen '!=' before, and weirdly, nothing came up on Google.

Answer (score 0):

!= means not equal to.

ex: c-a is not equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

`a != b` means that a is not equal to b. It's the same as `!(a == b)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an english translation of the code...

if c minus a is not equal to 0 AND d minus b is not equal to 0 then goto trap